# In Perl, how can I parse a CSV file where the fields contain comma separated values?

Tags: perl, csv, split

There is a `csv` file called `file.csv` like this: (this is just an example)

```
"Name","Alias","Phone","email","address"
"rob","rob","534235","rob@example.com","US,UK"
"nik","nik","976784","nik@example.com,nik@foram.org","UK"
"picy","pic","327654,823747","pic@example.com","US"
```

In this file there are 5 headers but values are more for few headers. Any header can have any number of values means more than 2 or 3.

I am trying to get output like this:

```
Name    Nickname    Phone        email                          address
rob     rob         534235       rob@example.com                US,UK
nik     nik         976784       nik@example.com,nik@foram.org  UK
picy    pic         327654,823747   pic@example.com             US
```

or any specific column, but for that column data will be like above.

I know about `split` function and limit in `spliting`:

```
while (<$fh>)
{
    my @data = split /,/, $_, 5;
}
```

but that is not working here.

How can I achieve this? Any Idea?

Comment: Split isn't smart enough to do what you want here.  You need at least a simple parser that can determine whether a field is a phone or email, for example.  At first you would need to be able to define the grammar and determine which type of field a value is - for example, it looks like 123455 would be a phone number - so the regex \d{6} would match only on phone numbers.  You could also define a regex for the email address, but the name/nickname distinction would be harder.  See [some parsers on cpan](http://search.cpan.org/~fdesar/Parse-Yapp-1.05/lib/Parse/Yapp.pm)

Comment: Download Text::CSV or Text::CSV_XS from CPAN and use it.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: then it is not a CSV file. It idea behind CPAN is that others have written, debugged, and saved their work for you to use. Not availing yourself to CPAN's modules means you are reinventing the wheel, which is costly and bug-prone.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP keeps changing the data thereby invalidating proposed solutions.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: That's my point: validating and rejecting the input. Too often "problems" are not problems but invalid input.

Comment: @SinanÜnür : **I have added and corrected the question.** Please unhold this question and undo your downvote.

Comment: It seems like if  a header have multiple values, they are always inside double quotes. So you could separate the different headers and values by first extracting comma separated values inside double quotes. This is a job for Text::CSV..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the updated information, the solution to your problem is now trivial:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV_XS;
use Text::Table::Tiny;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new;

my @data = ( $csv->getline(\*DATA) ); #header

while (my $row = $csv->getline(\*DATA)) {
    next unless @$row == @{ $data[0] };
    push @data, $row;
}

print Text::Table::Tiny::table(
    rows => \@data,
    header_row => 1,
);

__DATA__
"Name","Alias","Phone","email","address"
"rob","rob","534235","rob@example.com","US,UK"
"nik","nik","976784","nik@example.com,nik@foram.org","UK"
"picy","pic","327654,823747","pic@example.com","US"
```

Output:

```
+------+-------+---------------+-------------------------------+---------+
| Name | Alias | Phone         | email                         | address |
+------+-------+---------------+-------------------------------+---------+
| rob  | rob   | 534235        | rob@example.com               | US,UK   |
| nik  | nik   | 976784        | nik@example.com,nik@foram.org | UK      |
| picy | pic   | 327654,823747 | pic@example.com               | US      |
+------+-------+---------------+-------------------------------+---------+
```

You could also create a nested data structure by parsing both each line, and the fields in each line using the CSV parser:

```
while (my $row = $csv->getline(\*DATA)) {
    next unless @$row == @{ $data[0] };
    push @data, [
        map [ $csv->parse($_) ? $csv->fields : () ], @$row
    ];
}
```

This would mainly be useful if your main interest is in processing the data, not just printing it out.

Comment: Thank you so much. I also solved this problem by using `Text::CSV` module. But thanks for telling about creating nested data structure.